# Converting a Foreach to a for loop

Tags: php

I have a 3rd party script that loops through every returned value and echos it.

I want to limit the amount to 3 loops but am having issues.

current loop:

```
  foreach($json->data as $v)
  {
  echo  $v->from->name."<br>";
  }
```

I want to do something like:

```
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
                {
  echo  $v->from->name."<br>";
 }
```

Is there any work around without having to rework the whole script.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a foreach loop? If `$json->data` is an object, you cannot for loop an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $json is a integer-indexed array (although I doubt it)

```
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
    echo  $json->data->from->name."<br>";
}
```

otherwise a less elegant solution would be

```
$i = 0;

foreach($json->data as $v)
{
    echo  $v->from->name."<br>";
    if(++$i == 3) {break;}
}
```

finally

```
foreach(slice($json->data, 0, 3, TRUE) as $v)
{
    echo  $v->from->name."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert it in to for loop put an extra counter like this.

```
$count=0;
foreach($json->data as $v)
{
   if ($count == 3)
   { 
    break;
   }

   echo  $v->from->name."<br>";
   $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) the first 3 elements off the array and loop over those.